# Filter deeply nested list using Aggregation operations Spring data

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, aggregation-framework, mongotemplate

I'm having the below document

```
[ {
        "pageName": "Content_2",
        "domain": "bingo.com",
        "locale": "en-us",
        "contents": [
            {
                "contentName": "Template_2",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "title": "Company Name"                     
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Designation"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
{
        "version": 2,
        "pageName": "Content_3",
        "domain": "bingo.com",
        "locale": "en-in",
        "contents": [
            {
                "contentName": "Template_2",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "title": "Company Name"                          
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Designation"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }]
```

I'm filtering data on the basis of domain, locale and contentName. Till this point everything is working fine. Now, inside fields array, I want to show only those fields whose title matches with specific value. I'm not able to figure it out how to do it via aggregation operation. I have tried below snippet:

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
                    match(
                        where("domain").is(domain)
                        .and("contents.contentName").is(templateName)
                        .and("locale").in(criteria.getLocales())), 
                        project().and(new AggregationExpression() {
                        @Override
                        public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
                            DBObject filterExpression = new BasicDBObject();
                            filterExpression.put("input", "$contents.fields");
                            filterExpression.put("as", "field");
                            filterExpression.put("cond",
                                    new BasicDBObject("$eq", Arrays.<Object>asList("$$field.title", "Company Name")));
                            return new Document("$filter", filterExpression);
                        }

                }).as("field"));
AggregationResults<MyClass> list = mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregation, MyClass.class,
                MyClass.class);
```

It is returning all attributes as null. Please guide. I'm new to MongoDB. Thanks in advance;

Answer (score 0):

You can Use This *[Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)*

```
db.collection.aggregate([
        { $unwind: '$contents' },
        { $match: { "locale": "en-us", 
"domain": "bingo.com", "contents.contentName": "Template_2"} },
        { $unwind: '$contents.fields' },
        { $match: { 'contents.fields.title' : "Company Name" } },
        { $group: { _id: '$_id', 
              fields: { $push: { title: '$contents.fields.title'}}, 
              "locale" : {$first: "$locale"},
              "domain" : {$first: "$domain"},
              "pageName" : {$first: "$pageName"},
              'contentName': {$first: '$contents.contentName'}
              }
        },
        { $group: { _id: '$_id', 
         "locale" : {$first: "$locale"},
         "domain" : {$first: "$domain"},
         "pageName" : {$first: "$pageName"},
         contents: { $push: { "contentName": '$contentName', "fields": '$fields' }}, 
        }}
    ])
```

Or Simply Apply this. My Apology If I made blunder of syntax but try my best to make them right

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
                    unwind("contents),
                    match(
                         where("$domain").is(domain)
                        .and("$contents.contentName").is(templateName)
                        .and("$locale").in(criteria.getLocales())
                       ),
                    unwind("$contents.fields"),
                    match(where("$contents.fields.title").is(title)),
                    group("_id")
                     .push("$contents.fields.title").as("fields")
                     .push("$locale").as("locale")
                     .push("$domain").as("domain")
                     .push("$pageName").as("pageName")
                     .push("$contents.contentName").as("contentName"),
                 group("_id")
                 .push("locale").as("locale")
                 .push("domain").as("domain")
                 .push("pageName").as("pageName")
                 .push(new BasicDBObject
                   ("contentName", "$contentName").append
                   ("fields", "$fields").as("contents"))
                );
AggregationResults<MyClass> list = mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregation, MyClass.class,
                MyClass.class);
```

Run It your result is waiting for You...

Comment: thanks mate. I will try it. Only thing bothering me pushing attributes again because there are many other fields which I haven’t shown just make question to the point. I tried this unwind approach but code became messy. I was hoping for something short.

Comment: Hey use It and give Idea to more short it out:-  db.locations.aggregate([{$unwind:'$contents'},{$match:{"locale":"en-us","domain":"bingo.com","contents.contentName":"Template_2"}},{$unwind:'$contents.fields'},{$match:{'contents.fields.title':"Company Name"}},{$group:{_id:'$_id',fields:{$push:{title:'$contents.fields.title'}},"root":{$first:"$$ROOT"}}},{$group:{_id:'$_id',root:{$first:'$root'},contents:{$push:{"contentName":'$contentName',"fields":'$fields'}},}},{$replaceRoot:{newRoot:{$mergeObjects:["$root",{contents:'$contents'}]}}}])